# Keep the caret line always on the vertical middle of the buffer on Emacs

Tags: emacs

As the title say, is it possible to keep the editing line always on the vertical middle of the buffer?

In this way, when I would roll the screen, the text would move, but the editing line would be locked on the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used centered-cursor-mode for it. Here's the wiki:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/centered-cursor-mode.el

Comment: It's also possible to install it through package-install on emacs >= 24. It's sitting on the MELPA repository! :)

Thanks for the tip!!